# Android equivalent shell command 

Tags: android, shell

I am searching for the equivalent Linux command of following Android adb shell command:

```
%ANDROID%\platform-tools\adb.exe shell ^
 /system/bin/chmod 0777 /data/local/asl-native
```

This will be used to give the read and write permissions for a particular directory or file.

I have tried with the following Linux commands:

```
/system/bin/chmod u+rw /data/local/filename
```

However, it appears the file is not given permissions.

Comment: How are you trying to do this? With an app on the phone or with adb?

Comment: @Jerome I am trying with app only

Answer (score 1):

Most Android systems do not let you run as super user (i.e. root) and without that privilege, you cannot make this work.

You can read more bout how file storage works on Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Comment: Hi @jerome My mobile is rooted and also i have got the root permission from superuser application .

Comment: You are probably not using the 'su' hack correctly - post your code or better yet see the countless other questions on proper usage here.  Also, the chmod on most android builds only understands octal permissions such as 0777 and does not understand symbolic ones such as u+rw